# Why the Google play console account get ban

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I paid 25 USD for a google play console account but after 3 weeks my account get ban. I had publish few apps but after some days the account vanish. so can somebody help me to guide how we can make safe the account from getting banned.

I tried to Mail the google about the account that why I got banned but they only said you violate the rules, and not telling me what rules. one of my teachers told me that you should use the account on one device not to log in on many device and not to give access to any other person.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.